# React Routing : toggle switch onclick dynamic routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using a toggleswitch component in my react app. Within every event change of the toggle button, I want to change my routing, inside this component. Using react routing for the first time so I am pretty confused how can I handle it **within the component**.

If the state is true, I want to route it to "/", else i want it to "/videos". Here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ToggleSwitch extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      toggleValue: false
    };

    this.changeToggleMenuValue = this.changeToggleMenuValue.bind(this);
  }

  changeToggleMenuValue(event) {
    this.setState({
      toggleValue: !this.state.toggleValue
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="onoffswitch">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="onoffswitch"
          class="onoffswitch-checkbox"
          id="myonoffswitch"
          onClick={e => this.changeToggleMenuValue(e)}
        />
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
          <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
          <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ToggleSwitch;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the base routing structure in react is like below:

#### 1.Root Component:

basically you have a Root Component in your application, mainly the `<App />` component

#### 2.Inner Components:

inside of your `<App />` component you render 2 type of components:

1. components that should render in your routes
2. components that are shared between your routes ( which means that they are visible in every route )

type 2 components would render on each route, because they are out of `Switch`, like code structure below:

```
function App(props) {

  return (
    <>

      <Header />  

      <Switch>
       ...your routes
      </Switch>

      <SharedComponent_1 /> // may be a notif manager
      <SharedComponent_2 /> // may be a footer
      <SharedComponent_1 /> // other type of shared component 

    </>

  )

}
```

if you want to navigate from a route to another route inside of your component logic, you should ask your self two questions about your component:

1. is my component directly rendered by a `<Route ... />`?
2. is my component is just a simple sub component that rendered by another component which rendered by a `<Router ... />`

if your component has criteria of condition 1, then you already have `history, match, location` in your props and you can use `history.push('/targetRoute')` to navigate your user to another route.

however, if your component has criteras described in condition 2, you should wrap your component by a `withRouter` to get `history`, `match` and `location` into your props and user `push` function of `history` to navigate user around.

Answer (score -1):

This function should be work on your code:

```
changeToggleMenuValue() {
    this.setState({
      toggleValue: 
          this.state.toggleValue 
             ? history.push('') // or history.push('/')
             : history.push('/videos');
    });
  }
```

Comment: It changes the route but doesn't re render the components as I declared in my app.js